# need help wokring with openweather api adding skycons to application

Tags: javascript, api

tried to work with skycons in a weather app i'm working on but can't seem to get it to show up im trying to have the skycons show up with the current description. any ideas?
using openweather api

```
fetch(api)
.then(response =>{
  return response.json();
})
.then(data=>{
  console.log(data)
  const {temp}=data.list[4].main
  const {description, icon}=data.list[4].weather[0];

  // document.getElementById("temp").innerText=data.list[4].main.temp;
  temperatureDegree.textContent= temp;
  temperatureDescription.textContent= description;
  locationTimeZone.textContent= data.list[4].name;
  // set Icon
  setIcons(icon, document.querySelector('.icon'));

  });
});

}

function setIcons(icon,iconID){
  const skycons= new Skycons({color:"white"});
  const currentIcon = icon.toUpperCase();
  skycons.play();
  return skycons.set(iconID, skycons[currentIcon]);
}


});
```

Comment: What is the error log you are getting or what unexpected thing is happening?

Comment: there are no errors

Comment: Is there an inssue?